# HersheyFonts disappeared from OpenCV 4.2.0 Core Class file

Tags: java, android-studio, opencv

While I was studying the OpenCV codes that several developers posted for sample examples,

I caught an error **cannot resolve symbol 'FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX'**

Although I tried several [ways](https://kim-hoya.tistory.com/45) to resolve it, the error still has not been resolved.

After a little more Googleing,
I found that Core class in OpenCV 4.2.0 does not have static int group: FONT_HERSHEY_...

until OpenCV 3.4.0's Core Class there were HersheyFonts that helps  to configure font. [docs.opencv.org_link_ 3.4.0](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d0/de1/group__core.html)

but OpenCV 4.2.0's which I Installed in, does not have that variable anymore. [docs.opencv.org_link_4.2.0](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d0/de1/group__core.html)

**Hmm... Why is the `HersheyFont` variable deleted in the 4.2.0 version of Core Class and how should I use it to replace it?**

ex) code:: second line 'Core.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX' cause error
[View Full Code](https://medium.com/@aashari/simple-rectangle-detection-using-opencv-on-android-48e2a9a0586a#09f4): I'm sorry for kept revising it ㅠㅠ..

```
private void setLabel(Mat im, String label, MatOfPoint contour) {
    int fontface = Core.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;
    double scale = 3;//0.4;
    int thickness = 3;//1;
    int[] baseline = new int[1];
    Size text = Imgproc.getTextSize(label, fontface, scale, thickness, baseline);
    Rect r = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour);
    Point pt = new Point(r.x + ((r.width - text.width) / 2),r.y + ((r.height + text.height) / 2));
    Imgproc.putText(im, label, pt, fontface, scale, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), thickness);
}
```

Thank you all for your good answers every time and I hope you have a good day today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It wasn't deleted. Its module changed. **HersheyFonts** is available to use on [ImageProcessing/Drawing Functions module](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html).

Comment: Wow..!! Thank you!! Now I can use HersheyFonts in another way. As expected, the world of development is great!

Thanks for your kind answer! Have a nice day! >A</

Comment: similar to C++ in Java, I can import [Imgproc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/javadoc/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html)
to use FONT_HERSHEY !!! Very Thank you for finding Way to Solve the Problem 

Answer (score 2):

for Java you should use with the new OpenCV versions 4.0+.

required import

```
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
```

and now your constant

```
Imgproc.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
```

it was refactored and moved into a different class Imgproc. So your new code will be

```
private void setLabel(Mat im, String label, MatOfPoint contour) {
   int fontface = Imgproc.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;
```